# Does Spring JPA throw an error if save function is unsuccessful?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know if and what type of error is thrown by Spring JPA when trying to save an object to a database. The `JpaRepository.java` says to look at `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save`. However, I can not seem to find what type of error is thrown, if any at all. If no error is thrown, how do I go about checking if the save was successful?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The exception thrown will most likely depend on the cause. There might be for example OptimisticLockExpections, SQLExceptions. At least there will be an exception when something went wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Spring Data Repositories throw Spring's `DataAccessException`s that are structured to allow you to catch exceptions based on certain error scenarios. E.g. a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown to indicate foreign key violations.

The original exception is contained inside the exception being thrown so that you can get to it if you need to. By throwing a persistence technology agnostic exception, the repository clients don't get polluted with technology specific exceptions (e.g. Hibernate ones, JPA ones, MongoDB ones) so that you can exchange the repository implementation without breaking clients.

Answer (score 3):

It should throw a `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException`. Also, `CrudRepostiroy.save` returns you a new instance of the entity you gave it, if you get one back, that's a good sign that it saved.

Answer (score 0):

`CrudRepostiroy.save` have return type `the saved entity`

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity)
Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.
Parameters:
entity -
Returns:
the saved entity
```