# Spring JpaRepositroy.save() does not appear to throw exception on duplicate saves

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently playing around on Spring boot 1.4.2 in which I've pulled in Spring-boot-starter-web and Spring-boot-starter-jpa.

My main issue is that when I save a new entity it works fine (all cool).

However if I save a new product entity with the same id (eg a duplicate entry), it does not throw an exception. I was expecting ConstrintViolationException or something similar.

Given the following set up:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

ProductRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {}
```

JpaConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.verric.jpa.repository" )
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses ="com.verric.jpa")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Note JpaConfig.java and Application.java are in the same package.

ProductController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @PostMapping("createProduct")
    public void handle(@RequestBody @Valid CreateProductRequest request) {
        Product product = new Product(request.getId(), request.getName(), request.getPrice(), request.isTaxable());
        try {
            productRepository.save(product);
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getCause().getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and finally Product.java

```
@Entity(name = "product")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Product {

    protected Product() { /* jpa constructor*/ }

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private Long price;

    @Column
    private Boolean taxable;
}
```

The getter, setter and equalsHashcode.. are [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations.

**Miscellaneous:**

Spring boot : 1.4.2

Hibernate ORM: 5.2.2.FINAL

This issue happens regardless if I annotate the controller with or without `@Transactional`

The underlying db shows the exception clearly

```
2016-11-15 18:03:49 AEDT [40794-1] verric@stuff ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_pkey"
2016-11-15 18:03:49 AEDT [40794-2] verric@stuff DETAIL:  Key (id)=(test001) already exists
```

I know that is better (more common) to break the data access stuff into its own service layer instead of dumping it in the controller

The semantics of the controller aren't ReST

**Things I've tried:**

[Spring CrudRepository exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325413/spring-crudrepository-exceptions)

I've tried implementing the answer from this question, unfortunately my code never ever hits the DataAccesException exception

[Does Spring JPA throw an error if save function is unsuccessful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266248/does-spring-jpa-throw-an-error-if-save-function-is-unsuccessful)

Again similar response to the question above.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception

I tried adding the bean to my JPAconfig.java class that is:

```
   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }
```

But nothing seemed to happen.

Sorry for long post, ty in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are aware of  `CrudRepository.save()` is used for both insert and update. If an Id is non existing then it will considered an insert if Id is existing it will be considered update. You may get an Exception if your send the Id as null.

Since you don't have any other annotations apart from `@Id` on your `id` variable, The Unique Id generation must be handled by your code Or else you need to make use of `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Comment: After playing with it a bit, I did see that save acts as both a _save_ and an _update_. 
And the ids will be supplied by a client, they will most likely (if not certainly) be a UUID of some form.
So there is no way to get the exception the database is showing ?

Comment: You can get the exception if the ID is null. If is not, it will be considered as UPDATE and no exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 37):

My solution is a lot cleaner. Spring Data already provides a nice way for us to define how an entity is considered to be new. This can easily be done by implementing [`Persistable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) on our entities, as [documented in the reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites.strategies).

In my case, as is the OP's, the IDs come from an external source and cannot be auto generated. So the default logic used by Spring Data to consider an entity as new if the ID is null wouldn't have worked.

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Transient
    private boolean update;

    @Override
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isUpdate() {
        return this.update;
    }

    public void setUpdate(boolean update) {
        this.update = update;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return !this.update;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markUpdated() {
        this.update = true;
    }
}
```

Here, I have provided a mechanism for the entity to express whether it considers itself new or not by means of another transient boolean property called `update`. As the default value of `update` will be `false`, all entities of this type are considered new and will result in a `DataIntegrityViolationException` being thrown when you attempt to call `repository.save(entity)` with the same ID.

If you do wish to perform a merge, you can always set the `update` property to `true` before attempting a save. Of course, if your use case never requires you to update entities, you can always return `true` from the `isNew` method and get rid of the `update` field.

The advantages of this approach over checking whether an entity with the same ID already exists in the database before saving are many:

1. Avoids an extra round trip to the database
2. We cannot guarantee that by the time one thread has determined that this entity doesn't exist and is about to persist, another thread doesn't attempt to do the same and result in inconsistent data.
3. Better performance as a result of 1 and having to avoid expensive locking mechanisms.
4. Atomic
5. Simple

EDIT: Don't forget to implement a method using JPA callbacks that sets the correct state of the `update` boolean field just before persisting and just after loading from the database. If you forget to do this, calling `deleteAll` on the JPA repository will have no effect as I painfully found out. This is because the Spring Data implementation of `deleteAll` now checks if the entity is new before performing the delete. If your `isNew` method returns true, the entity will never be considered for deletion.

Comment: I tried it and all cool with PostgreSQL in integration phase, but I fail with H2 in memory while unit testing. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: This solution must be working well - it's just we have to pollute our entities with implementations and bunch of additional fields and methods now..

Answer (score 4):

To build upon Shazins answer and to clarify. the *CrudRepositroy.save()* or *JpaRespository.saveAndFlush()* both delegate to the following method

SimpleJpaRepository.java

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Hence if a user tries to **create** a new entity that so happens to have the same id as an existing entity Spring data will just update that entity.

To achieve what I originally wanted the only thing I could find was to drop back down to JPA solely, that is

```
@Transactional
@PostMapping("/createProduct")
public Product createProduct(@RequestBody @Valid Product product) {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(product);
        entityManager.flush();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    return product;
}
```

Here if we try to persist and **new** entity with an id already existing in the database it will throw will throw the constraint violation exception  as we originally wanted.

Comment: Yes.  Spring Data is designed in a way that does not make any real sense if you're using keys with specified values -- the design really relies on using an automatic key generation process that ensure there are no duplicates.  There are other alternatives: within a single transaction, checking `repository.exists(id)` before calling `save()` would work, but honestly the simplest approach is likely to be adding an extra autogenerated key and then adding a unique constraint on your domain-type key.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are 3 scenarios here:

#### 1. Setting ID manually

If there is no choice(like the OP), i.e if you are setting your own id "manually", Spring Data JPA is assuming that you want to check if there are duplicates(hence the **SELECT**), so it will do a **"(i)SELECT + (ii)INSERT"** if there is no existing record *or* a **"(i)SELECT + (ii)UPDATE"** if there is already an existing record.

In short, 2 SQLs!

#### 2. Use an ID Generator

Cleaner & better, for example:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "my-uuid")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "my-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
 private UUID id;
```

Result: there is **ALWAYS** only **1 INSERT** statement.

#### 3. Implement Persistable and isNew()

This has already been brilliantly answered by @adarshr, but is also more painful, i.e to implement `Persistable`(instead of `Serializable`), and implement the `isNew()` method.

Result: Also, **1 INSERT** statement.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) Spring persists an entity if does not exists or merge, this means update, the existing one:

> Saving an entity can be performed via the CrudRepository.save(…)-Method. It will persist or merge the given entity using the underlying JPA EntityManager. If the entity has not been persisted yet Spring Data JPA will save the entity via a call to the entityManager.persist(…)-Method, otherwise the entityManager.merge(…)-Method will be called.