# Spring JPA repo does not seem to save nor does it throws any exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE(FINCHLEY)` `starter-data-jpa 2.0.5.RELEASE.
The scenario is pretty basic, build an entity and save it.

Let's go through the code for better context before we go through texts.

Entity class `(Asset)`: The id(primary key) does not generate automatically because we basically get a unique `UUID.toString()` from another source which is assuredly unique.

```
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET", schema = "SCHEMA")
public class Asset implements Persistable<String> {
// Propriety code hence column names removed. 
//Let's just assume column names are fine, since when I am doing a find(), results are cool

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String creditPool;

    private int quantity;

    private int assetStatusTypeId;

    private long assetTypeId;

    private int ageOfAsset;

    //The below snippet is part of Persistable<String> to force a new entry. Newly added following an answer in stackoverflow.

    //Here, update is basically false by default, 
    //so as you can see isNew() will always return true forcing jpa to save a new record

    @Transient
    private boolean update;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return !this.update;
    }
}
```

As per the comments I have added, you see I added that snippet because we are not autogenerating the `id`.

**Without the snippet and Persistable the issue is same btw.**

My custom repository class has the below custom save function because of business reasons.

```
@Override
   public <S extends T> S save(S entity, long value) {
       entity.someParams(args getting from from a jar) //which is really fine
       return super.save(entity);
   }
```

Code from which `save` is being called is below

```
Asset asset = Asset.builder()
.id(UUID.randomId().toString()) //see always unique
.assetStatusTypeId(a valid id)
.assetTypeId(a valid id)
.creditPool("pool")
.quantity(integer value)
.ageOfAsset(integer value).build();
repo.save(asset);
```

I have verified the builder mutiple times and, It indeed creates a `Asset` object without fail.

**But the culprit `save` never gets executed.**

I have turned on the `showSQL:true` to check whether the insert query gets called or not. But I see no such queries.

Hibernate properties:

```
jpa:
  show-sql: true
  properties:
    hibernate:
      enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      jdbc:
        batch_size: 5
```

I considered a scenario where even with all the safe checks, JPA might be treating it as a update scenario,

**I ignored the save and used `persist` as well. Even then no insertion.**

`repo.persist(asset);`

Please help on this.

stackoverflow [Sources for my workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605834/spring-jparepositroy-save-does-not-appear-to-throw-exception-on-duplicate-save) and the duplicates.
Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should flush after the save or directly use saveAndFlush(asset).

Comment: The save does not get executed and that's the issue and you want me to to flush after saving ?

Comment: Save will only get executed if you flush your transaction to the DB.