# CrudRepository's save method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

I just implemented the CrudRepository interface and I figured out I cannot use the apply the orElseThrows to throws a custom exception to the default save method's return.

What am I supposed to do in order achieve this support ? Should I overwrite the save method ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266248/does-spring-jpa-throw-an-error-if-save-function-is-unsuccessful

Comment: It's not really related though. I wonder if I'd have to overwrite the save method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should overwrite the save method. Since `orElseThrow()` is a method of `java.util.Optional` class your method should return an `Optional` object.